# JPA / Hibernate get Objects grouped by year/month

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I would like to create a database request which returns my Objects from a Class group by Year/Month.

The idea is to get via JPA / Hibernate a `List<Object[]>` theList:
`Object[0]` = a list from my objects
`Object[1]` = the year/month

Any idea how I should create the SQL statement for this?

I´ve tried this:

```
SELECT count(m), m, month (m.myField) AS timeValue, year(m.myField) AS yearValue 
FROM MyClass m
GROUP BY m, month (m.myField), year(m.myField)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you want all objects, just grouped, but the SQL concept of grouping always also means aggregating. Just read all the data then and group it into a hash map with java.